# List all the files that ever existed in a Git repository

Tags: git

Do you have a clean way to list all the files that ever existed in specified branch?

Comment: "Ever exist"? Does it include the files that exist in a commit\version several months ago and they may be deleted at current commit\version?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

This is a simplified variation of Strager's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543383/313192):

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-status | cut -f2- | sort -u
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Jakub for teaching me a bit more in the comments, this version has a shorter pipeline and gives git more opportunity to get things right.

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -u
```

Comment: @Dustlin: Add --diff-filter=A option (list only added files). Current version (without sed filtering only added files) would fail if you have enabled rename detection and have renames in history. I think you can then use --name-only instead of --name-status and remove 'cut -f2-' from pipeline.

Comment: In one of my repos, I get quite a few duplicate lines (including a number of blank lines at the beginning of the output) with the second command that aren't dupes with the first.

Comment: If you need a bit more info than the file name: $ git log --pretty=format:"%h %an [%cd]: %s" --name-only | cut -f2- | sort -u | grep Filename.ext

Comment: *Note: `--all` is something you will need if you have more than a single orphaned tip. Eg, multiple separate histories in one repo.*

Comment: `--diff-filter=A` ignores files that were created by copying an already existing file, so adding it may not _always_ be what you want.

Comment: @Dustin "**Ever** exist", does it include the files that exist in a commit\version several months ago and they **may be deleted** at current commit\version?

Answer (score 19):

This does the right thing for checking if a filename was ever present in the *repo* not just on the current branch.

```
git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort - | grep fubar
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sort -u` ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is two useful alias: FindFile `ff` and FindFilewithCopies `ffc`:

```bash
# Find if one file ever had into repository
ff = "!git log --pretty=format: --name-status --all -M -B | sort -u | grep $1   #"
# The same as above but showing copied files
ffc = "!git log --pretty=format: --name-status --all -C -M -B | sort -u | grep $1 #"
```

You get information about file names and operations with them.

Sample use:

```
$ git ff create
A       database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
A       database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
A       database/migrations/2015_05_11_200932_create_boletin_table.php
A       database/migrations/2015_05_15_133500_create_usuarios_table.php
D       database/migrations/2015_05_12_000000_create_users_table.php
M       database/migrations/2015_05_11_200932_create_boletin_table.php
R051    database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php    database/migrations/2015_05_12_000000_create_users_table.php

$ git ffc create
A       database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
A       database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
A       database/migrations/2015_05_11_200932_create_boletin_table.php
A       database/migrations/2015_05_15_133500_create_usuarios_table.php
C052    database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php    database/migrations/2015_05_11_210246_create_boletin_nosend_table.php
D       database/migrations/2015_05_12_000000_create_users_table.php
M       database/migrations/2015_05_11_200932_create_boletin_table.php
R051    database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php    database/migrations/2015_05_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run `git-log --name-status`, which echoes something like:

```
commit afdbbaf52ab24ef7ce1daaf75f3aaf18c4d2fee0
Author: Your Name <your@email.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 12 13:28:34 2008 -0700

    Added test file.

A       test
```

Then extract files added:

```
git-log --name-status | sed -ne 's/^A[^u]//p' | sort -u
```