# git equivalent of "svn -v status"

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I want to know the list of files that are known to version control.

I know that in SVN, you can do something like:

```
svn -v status
```

then you get a list of

> "[rev#1] [rev#2] [creator] [file
>   name]"

rev#1 is the last revision that has this file and rev#2 is the first revision that has this file.

**This list contains all the files that are tracked by svn other than only the ones that have local changes.**

I wonder how to do this using **GIT**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have [this proposition](http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=237) for an equivalent of svn status with git:

```
git config alias.svn-status \!"\
{ \
git ls-files -o --directory -t ; \
git status | grep --color=never 'deleted:    ' | sed 's|^.*deleted:    ||' | sed 's|^|D |' ; \
git ls-files -m -s | awk '{print \$NF}' | sort -u | sed 's|^|M |' ; \
} \
| sort -k 2 \
| sed 's|^\\(.\\) *|\\1      |'"
```

I suspect `git log --name-status` mentioned by [Techism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649192/techism) (in the comments) in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/git-list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed) might make the alias shorter.

Its variant is actually based on `diff --name-status`:

```
svn-status = "! git ls-files --exclude-per-directory=.gitignore --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude --exclude-from=$HOME/.gitignore --others -t | sed 's| |\t|'; git diff HEAD --name-status "
```

Answer (score 3):

git status

That shows a status much like svn status command.

EG:

```
> $ git status
> # On branch master
> # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
> #
> # Changed but not updated:
> #   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
> #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working
> directory)
> #
> # modified:   Gemfile
> # modified:   Gemfile.lock
> # modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
> # modified:   app/controllers/home_controller.rb
> # modified:   app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
> ...
```

For redundancy sake, repeating answer from this similar question:

[List all the files that ever existed in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/git-list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed)

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -
```

or

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-status | cut -f2- | sort -u
```

Comment: "svn -v status" shows all the files that are tracked by svn. I think "git status" only shows the files that are locally changed.

Comment: Actually:  This thread answers your question I think...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/git-list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed

Comment: thanks, the command that you posted above does help me quite a bit. Is there any way to filter out the files that no longer exist?

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

Here's a good place to start.