# How can I list all the deleted files in a Git repository?

Tags: git

I know Git stores information of when files get deleted and I am able to check individual commits to see which files have been removed, but is there a command that would generate a list of every deleted file across a repository's lifespan?

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this answer but just looking to see a list of files added, renamed, deleted, modified, etc, from one commit hash or branch to another, do this: `git diff --name-status commit_hash`.

Answer (score 531, accepted):

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

See [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

If you don't want all the information about which commit they were removed in, you can just add a `grep delete` in there.

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```

Comment: **Warning:** This lists any files you've deleted. If you've deleted a file, then created a new file with the same name, it **will** show up on this list, even though there's an extant file there.

Comment: You should also look at the **git whatchanged** command.  It's pretty cool.

Comment: This would list also the renames as deletes. To skip these use `git log --find-renames --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete`

Comment: With git 2.9 detection of renames is activated by default. To see these again as deletes use ``git log --no-renames --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete``

Comment: If you know the name of the file then this will give a bit more context (15 lines +/-) around the results: `git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep -15 <name_of_file>`

Comment: Beware using `grep delete` because if the commit message has the word delete, it'll be picked up as well. Use `grep 'delete mode'` instead.

Comment: This does not list files, only the commits that contains changes of those files. The answer by Mark Longair does the right thing.

Comment: it worked! How to show the log from a specific folder? I tried '-- folder' and doen't seems to work

Comment: @Mr.Black `man git whatchanged` recommends `git log` instead for general use: “New users are encouraged to use git-log(1) instead. … The command is kept primarily for historical reasons”.  I would use `git log --patch` instead.

Answer (score 112):

This does what you want, I think:

```
git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D | sort -u
```

... which I've just taken more-or-less directly from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/git-list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed).

This prints only file paths without other info:

```
BETA.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
files/en-us/api/file_api/index.html
files/en-us/games/index/index.md
files/en-us/games/visual-js_game_engine/index.html
files/en-us/games/visual_js_ge/index.html
files/en-us/games/visual_typescript_game_engine/index.html
...
```

Answer (score 51):

If you're only interested in seeing the currently deleted files, you can use this:

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

if you then want to remove them (in case you deleted them not using "git rm") pipe that result to xargs git rm

```
git ls-files --deleted | xargs git rm
```

Comment: This shows only files in the index that have been deleted in the working copy.  The OP wants all files that have ever been deleted.

Comment: or `git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)`

Comment: even though it's not what the OP wanted, this was still useful for at least myself, since I had trouble phrasing my query properly in a search

Answer (score 22):

Citing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271435/list-all-changed-files-with-change-status-between-git-commits-added-modified/15273966#15273966) Stack Overflow answer.

It is a pretty neat way to get type-of-change **(A:Added, M:Modified, D:Deleted)** for each file that got changed.

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~1000
```

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to somehow constrain the results here's a nice one:

```
$ git log --diff-filter=D --summary | sed -n '/^commit/h;/\/some_dir\//{G;s/\ncommit \(.*\)/ \1/gp}'
delete mode 100644 blah/some_dir/file1 d3bfbbeba5b5c1da73c432cb3fb61990bdcf6f64
delete mode 100644 blah/some_dir/file2 d3bfbbeba5b5c1da73c432cb3fb61990bdcf6f64
delete mode 100644 blah/some_dir/file3 9c89b91d8df7c95c6043184154c476623414fcb7
```

You'll get all files deleted from `some_dir` (see the sed command) together with the commit number in which it happen. Any sed regex will do (I use this to find deleted file types, etc)

Comment: I believe that's way to complicated to be useful in daily developer life. Instead, if you want to list files deleted from current directory, just do: `git log --diff-filter=D .`

Comment: The case I had was that the directory was also removed and I just new part of the name.

Answer (score 5):

Since Windows doesn't have a `grep` command, this worked for me in PowerShell:

```
git log --find-renames --diff-filter=D --summary | Select-String -Pattern "delete mode" | sort -u > deletions.txt
```

Comment: What is `Select-String`?

Comment: It's a PowerShell cmdlet. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Windows has [FIND](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) and [FINDSTR](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), though I must admit I have never used them. Installing [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) is the easiest way. An alternative is the bloated [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

Answer (score 5):

Show all deleted files in *some_branch*

```
git diff origin/master...origin/some_branch --name-status | grep ^D
```

or

```
git diff origin/master...origin/some_branch --name-status --diff-filter=D
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because it would contain all files with a D in them. You need something like
`git diff origin/master...origin/some_branch --name-status | grep ^D` or `git diff origin/master...origin/some_branch --name-status --diff-filter=D`

Answer (score 2):

This will get you a list of all files that were deleted in all branches, sorted by their path:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep "delete mode 100" | cut -c 21- | sort > deleted.txt
```

Works in msysgit (2.6.1.windows.1). Note we need "delete mode 100" as git files may have been commited as mode 100644 or 100755.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the names purely separated by a newline character, you can use the `--name-only` flag like this:

```
git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only <old-commit-hash> <new-commit-hash>
```