# Find commit where file has been deleted in GitHub (without cloning repo)

Tags: github

Is there a way to find and display in which commit a file has been deleted in Github, but without cloning it locally? For example, using the website's online search form?

Comment: Anyway, for a general Git solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this without cloning the repo.