# Where is "Go test" source code documented?

Tags: go

I'm looking for the source code of the "go test" command which afaik does some funky stuff (exports the functions, recompiles the package etc). So far I could find only "[testing](http://golang.org/src/testing/)" and the [cmd/go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) doc

Comment: why the vote to close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start looking in the `cmd/go` package, where most of the [go commands](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) are defined:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1ba29926f3bfd245d46cf1f287716290bc2f1034/src/cmd/go/test.go (last known commit with `src/cmd/go/test.go`, Go 1.8)
Then [commit 4efe925](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/4efe9250e5e182c8269a2b98497a9bdea4875c8f) shows `src/cmd/go/test.go` being renamed/moved to `src/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go` in Go 1.9, Jan. 2017.
Last modification: [commit ca33f33](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ca33f33b1420cf333c59c6458bb9bc8910c91ecb) in Oct. 2018 for Go 1.12.

Comment: The link is broken, and I'm darned if I can find the current source.  (I'm looking for the "go run" source.)  Do you know where it is now?  (https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/cmd is the tree where I would have expected to find it.)

Comment: No problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203551/6309 allowed me to find the last commit and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054951/6309 show me the new location!