# Github has lost my folder

Tags: git, github

On my staging branch, I committed a folder `migrations_lar` with 1 migration file in it.  I found the commit where I added it on November 29th.  When I look at the staging branch now, the entire `migrations_lar` folder is gone.  I need to find out when it disappeared.  I also want to know if anything else disappeared.

Here is what I have learned:

I ran `git log -- database/migrations_lar`
[image: git log -- database/migrations_lar]

The commit where I added the folder has the message "Implement Partner Webhook".  None of those other commits delete the folder.

When I get on GitHub and check the status of the staging branch after various commits, I see that folder appears and disappears regularly:
[image]
The highlighted rows DO NOT have my commit, and do not have the migrations_lar folder.
The bottom commit has the migrations_lar folder when it was initially created long ago, without my file in it.

I am just completely stumped as to how or when this got lost, and what got lost with it.  Any help?

## Update

Months ago I added the migrations_lar folder with Laravel's default migrations in it.
At some point someone deleted the files therefore the folder.

On Nov 29th I added the folder and the new migration.

At some point after that (I assume) someone created a bad merge with the original deletion.  I don't know how this happened.  Any clue on how I could find the commit that shows when that file was deleted?!

Comment: You’re probably aware, but to make it explicitly clear: nothing got lost. One of the commits deletes the file. Git doesn’t keep track of folders, so if you delete a file in a folder, the folder will also be deleted. Merges mean that the file isn’t necessarily disappearing and reappearing in history. A bad merge commit could also have deleted it. Try a `git log --stat`.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your help.  I am aware that git doesn't manage folders, and that there *HAS* to be a commit where it was deleted.  I just can't find one.  There are over a hundred commits and I've gone through many of them.  I also suspect it was a bad merge commit, but it would show in the change for that commit right?  Read my update for the likely cause of the bad merge.

Comment: Tried a bisect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Ryan.  I tried git bisect to find the commit that caused the issue.  And I think it helped.  I think it identified the commit, but I ignored it.

Then I called `git checkout HEAD^; ls database/migrations_lar` until I found the commit that had the folder.  I found the commit string of the the faulting commit and ran `git show https://github.com/completesolar/HelioTrack/commit/226d0b8f940a7bec524360a0f631d87f46dfaab8`.

Sure enough I saw

```
...017_11_28_100558_create_organizations_table.php |  54 ---
```

Then i realized this commit was when I merged a Pull Request.  I reviewed that Pull request and sure enough I had missed that full on code review.  From that pull request I revied the 30 commits on the Pull Request and found the offending failed merge.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, beside bisect, is to `git log`, focusing on deletion.
See "[Find when a file was deleted in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13028151/6309)"

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | \
  sed -n '/^commit/h;/\/some_dir\//{G;s/\ncommit \(.*\)/ \1/gp}'
```

On Mac:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | \
  sed -n -e '/^commit/h' -e '\:/:{' -e G -e 's/\ncommit \(.*\)/ \1/gp' -e }
```

That would list all commits where files within a folder have disappeared.