# Github - find when a directory was removed

Tags: git, github

I'd like to know when a directory was removed from a github repo. Is this possible somehow without manually checking the commits? I'd prefer solutions which don't require cloning the repo from github and installing additional tools, but if there is no other option, I can accept those too.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git) talks about the same thing in the context of files instead of folders - perhaps it will work for you as well.

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, only files.

Comment: If you have an idea of what the contents of that folder was, perhaps you could search for a deleted file *within* that folder.

Comment: @Joe Thanks! :-)