# How to recover deleted files with git on moved folder

Tags: git

Several months ago I did a refactoring of paths to several java modules. Now it seems that I have forgotten to move the src/test directory of one of the modules and instead deleted it...

How can I recover all these deleted files? Note that the path to the module where the files was located, is deleted, and I cannot remember the earlier path?

Comment: Can you find a commit from way back when, and check that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755406/930271) you can find the last commit where the file/folder was modified with this command:

```
git log --full-history -- src/test
```

Once you find the commit where the file exists you can checkout it into your current working tree with [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203551/930271):

```
git checkout <SHA>^ -- <path-to-file>
```

Note that `<SHA>` is the hash of the commit where the folder was deleted, so you make a checkout to the previous commit