# How to find commit at which file tracked by git lfs was deleted

Tags: git, git-log, git-lfs

I'm trying to find commit at which some specific `*.npy` file was deleted.

`git log --full-history  -- <my_file>` not showing anything

[Find when a file was deleted in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git)

So I assume this file was added via git lfs.

How to find commit at which file tracked by git lfs was deleted?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the SHA of the file, maybe this can help :

`git log --source --all -p  -S <SHA here>`

it searches through the entire commit history for a specific string (the SHA in this case), and since git-lfs stores files as text files containing the SHA of the actual file, you can track it down like that.