# How can I restore an old file already committed/pushed in GitHub?

Tags: file, github, git-commit

I have a hobby project with many commits, and somewhere in the past I probably accidentally removed a file which is committed/pushed.

Is there a way to find / restore the file? (or getting the contents, it's a text file).

I don't know in which commit it has happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the file name, you can [find when it was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16635324/6309)

```
git log --full-history -1 -- aFile
```

From there, knowing the commit (thanks to the previous query), you can restore it with:

```
git restore <commit>~ -- aFile
```

The `~` would take the commit parent (where the file was still there)

Comment: I found out I cannot use git commands directly from the console (as I use GitHub) and Eclipse, but I will try to find a way to enter git commands.