# How to find the commit that contained a specific file in Git history?

Tags: git, search

I found a reference on a public repository for a file that is now no longer in `master`.

What is the fastest way to find the commit that first (or last) contained that file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+file

Comment: This question was answered previously; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git ; in short use `git log --full-history  -- myfile`