# How to find the git log or commit history for a specific file using PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, git-log

I wanted to find the commit history for a specific file/path using powershell. Based on the last commit message,if it was deleted i am invoking a deleted function. which it invokes a rest API to delete it from Azure else it will go to next.

Here what i am trying to do

> ```
>   $commited_file_name = $([io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Line)) #This gives Me the filename
>
>   $path = $_.Line #This Gives me the complete Path. They change it dynamically based on the committed file in the Azure Devops Repo
> ```

by make using of the above lines i'm passing the following git commands to fetch commit history of a specic file. most of my files are Json files.

By referencing these two [Find when a file was deleted in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git) and [How to find a deleted file in the project commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/how-to-find-a-deleted-file-in-the-project-commit-history). As i couldn't find how to do it via powershell.

Here is what i Did.

```
      #Tried to get the commit history using a Path
      $commit_log = git log --full-history -1 [$path]
      WriteDebug "Commit Log:$commit_log" #[However this is not returning anything ]

      #Then tried to get the commit history using a Filename
      $commit_file = git log --all --full-history -1 -- "**/$commited_file_name.json.*"
      WriteDebug  "Commit File history:$commit_file" #[This is also not returing anything]
      
      #And it is failing at this point and invoked the DotheNextTask function even if the last commit of the file was deleted.

      $filter_commit = $("$commit_file" | grep -c "Deleted")
      if ("$filter_commit" -ne 0 ) {
        Deletefile
      }
      else{
        DotheNextTask
      }
```

is there something i'm not doing right? or am i missing something here.

Comment: Can someone explain where I'm doing wrong and what I'm supposed to do inorder to get git commit info for a specific file, via PowerShell. As here I'm passing PowerShell variable as argument value to git command and it's returning nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code and tested against it. Now it is displaying the output.

Please note, if you're using PowerShell, the hyphens have to be escaped: git log '--' [file path].

```
$commit_file = git log --all --full-history -1 $("**/$commited_file_name.*")
WriteDebug  "Commit File history:$commit_file" #[Fetches previous commit history from all branches for that specific file]
```