# Find when a file was deleted in Git before commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to know [when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398/find-when-a-file-was-deleted-in-git), *before* the deletion has been commited ?

thanks

Comment: As in "at 13:00 the deletion was commited, but at 12:45" the file was deleted? No, git doesn't store that kind of information. Its history is restricted to commit history.

Comment: yeah... actually, I meant, without even committing the deletion -- but I guess the answer is also negative

Comment: extract from chatGPT answer :) "...Therefore, if a file has been deleted but the deletion has not yet been committed, there is no way to know when the deletion occurred using Git commands. "

Comment: Yeah, if you don't do it *with git* or *to git*, git will not know about it. Btw., ChatGPT has ... issues. Specifically when it comes to giving technical answers. Read [the SO policy for details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).