# Finding the commit of deletion of a file

Tags: git

I am looking for the full history of a deleted file from git repo, but getting only single commit of its creation. The file is not present on the Filesystem:

```
ls path/to/file/foo
ls: cannot access 'path/to/file/foo': No such file or directory
```

But I can see its history only for the creation with:

```
git log --full-history --all -- path/to/file/foo
commit dc78de658dd1fa8dff4b32b2e49b37d011afad2b (origin/bar, bar)
Author: Joe Dow
Date:   Thu May 12 15:52:54 2000 +0300

Foo added
```

Also the file was not deleted outside git:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But how can I see commit where the file was deleted?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Are you sure the file deletion was committed and isn't just local to your working tree? What does `git status` have to say about the file? Please [edit] your question and include the output of `git status path/to/file/foo`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16635324/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+deletion

Comment: @knittl that would be too silly if the file was deleted outside of git :)

Comment: @phd actually, I used `--full-history` too

Comment: I think I understand what happened - the file was created in a branch was never merged to master. Then this branch was deleted