# List files in git history that were deleted but *not* re-added

Tags: git

I'm trying to list the names of all files that existed at any point in a branch's history but were subsequently deleted and do not exist in the *latest* commit on that branch.

Answers in other similar (but not identical) questions suggest this:

```
git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D
```

but this lists all the individual file deletion operations from all commits in the branch's history, without considering whether the files were re-added.

I use git just regularly enough to be dangerous and my terminology might be a little off so here's a concrete example of what I'm trying to do:

```
git init

:: add three files
echo aaa > aaa.txt
echo bbb > bbb.txt
echo ccc > ccc.txt
git add --all
git commit -m "initial commit"

:: delete aaa.txt, bbb.txt
del aaa.txt
del bbb.txt
git add --all
git commit -m "delete aaa.txt, bbb.txt"

:: re-add aaa.txt
echo zzz > aaa.txt
git add --all
git commit -m "re-add aaa.txt"
```

I'm trying to work out what command I need to list just `bbb.txt` - I don't care that `aaa.txt` was deleted at some point because it was later re-added so it currently exists in the tip of the branch.

I'm also not concerned about the *contents* of the files, just identifying the names / paths of the "missing" files.

Specifically, I'd like the output from this hypothetical command to be:

```
bbb.txt
```

If the output could also list the *most recent* commit that the "missing" files were deleted from as well that be a bonus, but not essential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a Unix shell environment, you can use [`comm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) from `coreutils` to compare the list of deleted files with a list of files in the current revision:

```bash
$ comm -23  \
    <(git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D | sort | uniq | grep -v '^$') \
    <(git ls-files | sort)

bbb.txt
```

Breaking this down:

- The `comm` command compares two sorted files line-by-line. Passing `-23` causes it only print only lines contained in the first file but not in the second.
- The two "files" being passed to `comm` are [process substitutions](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (`<(...)`).

  - The first process substitution is a modified version of the deleted-file command from the question. The output is passed through `sort | uniq` to obtain a sorted list of unique file paths. The output is also passed through `grep -v '^$'` to remove a pesky blank line.
  - The second process substitution uses [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) to fetch the names of  all files in the current revision. These are sorted using `sort` to keep `comm` happy.
- The result is a list of all files which have been deleted at some point in the history and which are also not contained in the current revision.

---

#### Bonus: getting the most recent commit that deleted each deleted file

Once you have the paths to the deleted files, you can [determine what commit they were deleted in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6839398/11082165) using

```bash
$ git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file>
```

So to get all deleted files and the commits they were deleted in, you could use something like

```bash
$ comm -23  \
    <(git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D | sort | uniq | grep -v '^$') \ 
    <(git ls-files | sort) \ 
    | while IFS= read -r deleted; do                            
        echo "$deleted" $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- "$deleted");
     done
bbb.txt 67e026eb45545f9d095ade3ad8f7fe9d5ad3590e
```

---

<sub>If you are in the unfortunate situation where you need to handle newlines *in* file names, I have verified this approach still works if you use NUL-delimited lines everywhere by passing `-z` to `comm`, `git log`, `sort`, `uniq`, and `grep`.</sub>

Comment: @mclayton Good catch! I found a better (and simpler) approach that correctly accounts for re-added/re-deleted files

Comment: Fab. I've posted a PowerShell port based on your answer since that's what I'm actually using, but yours is the original, so I'll mark it as the answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --pretty=format:%h --name-status \
| awk 'NF==1 { commit=$1 } NF>1 && !seen[$2]++ && $1=="D" && $1=commit' FS=$'\t'
```

"In `git log`'s name-status output with a just-the-hash header, if there's just one field, it's the commit id, so remember it, otherwise if we haven't seen the filename before this is the last thing ever done to it, if it's a deletion, we want this line, we know they're all deletions so just replace the `D` with the commit id."

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to tie other answers down to a particular language / platform, but I'm specifically using PowerShell (Core) 7.3 (to be executed on Windows *and* Linux) - I've adapted [@Brian61354270's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247006/3156906) and just posting here to give something back...

```
$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = "Standard";

$deleted_files = (
    git log -z --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D
).Split(0, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyValues) | select-object -unique;

$current_files = (
    git ls-files -z
).Split(0, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyValues)

$missing_files = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $deleted_files -DifferenceObject $current_files `
    | where-object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } `
    | select-object -ExpandProperty "InputObject";

$results = $missing_files | foreach-object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        "File"   = $_
        "Commit" = (git rev-list -z -n 1 HEAD -- $_)
    }
}

$results | format-table

File    Commit
----    ------
bbb.txt 01f2686a4a287c11544afaa34a04ef69db35bae1
```