# How can I get the filename (as created) when letter case differs?

Tags: git, powershell, github, powershellforgithub

Windows and PowerShell are almost always case insensitive. Sometimes that is convenient.

git is case sensitive. Sometimes that is convenient.

A file is committed in a repo named `a_TEST_file.txt`. The user passes `a_test_file.txt` to the PowerShell script. The PowerShell script queries git about the filename and gets a `not found` response.

I tried several things including `Resolve-Path` and `Convert-Path`. They seem unrelated to this issue, but I am reaching for anything that might work?

Must I simply document that the filename(s) given to the script are case-sensitive?

How can I get the original filename using correct letter case?

```sh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '.\a_test' | Out-Null
Push-Location -Path '.\a_test'
git init
'a test' | Set-Content -Path .\a_TEST_file.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'a commit'
git log .\a_TEST_file.txt
git log .\a_test_file.txt
$null -eq $(git log .\a_test_file.txt)

Get-ChildItem '.\a_TEST_file.txt'
Get-ChildItem '.\a_test_file.txt'
Get-ChildItem '.\a_test_file.txt' |
    Select-Object -Property Name,FullName,ResolvedTarget,PSPath
Resolve-Path -Path '.\a_test_file.txt'
Convert-Path -Path '.\a_test_file.txt'

Pop-Location
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path '.\a_test'
```

Here is an execution of the commands.

```sh
PS C:\src> New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '.\a_test' | Out-Null
PS C:\src> Push-Location -Path '.\a_test'
PS C:\src\a_test> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/src/a_test/.git/
PS C:\src\a_test> 'a test' | Set-Content -Path .\a_TEST_file.txt
PS C:\src\a_test> git add .
PS C:\src\a_test> git commit -m 'a commit'
[main (root-commit) 7fd198b] a commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a_TEST_file.txt
PS C:\src\a_test> git log .\a_TEST_file.txt
commit 7fd198b556dd1dabf8c9a47369e71d424cf995bd (HEAD -> main)
Author: lit <lit@myco.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 18 04:40:29 2023 -0600

    a commit
PS C:\src\a_test> git log .\a_test_file.txt
PS C:\src\a_test> $null -eq $(git log .\a_test_file.txt)
True
PS C:\src\a_test>
PS C:\src\a_test> Get-ChildItem '.\a_TEST_file.txt'

    Directory: C:\src\a_test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2023-11-18    04:40              8 a_TEST_file.txt

PS C:\src\a_test> Get-ChildItem '.\a_test_file.txt'

    Directory: C:\src\a_test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2023-11-18    04:40              8 a_test_file.txt

PS C:\src\a_test> Get-ChildItem '.\a_test_file.txt' | Select-Object -Property Name,FullName,ResolvedTarget,PSPath

Name            FullName                      ResolvedTarget                PSPath
----            --------                      --------------                ------
a_test_file.txt C:\src\a_test\a_test_file.txt C:\src\a_test\a_test_file.txt Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\src\a_test\a_test_file.txt

PS C:\src\a_test> Resolve-Path -Path '.\a_test_file.txt'

Path
----
C:\src\a_test\a_test_file.txt

PS C:\src\a_test> Convert-Path -Path '.\a_test_file.txt'
C:\src\a_test\a_test_file.txt
PS C:\src\a_test>
PS C:\src\a_test> Pop-Location
PS C:\src> Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path '.\a_test'
PS C:\src>
```

Comment: Can you show the git command you’re using that returns “not found”? You can get a (case-sensitive) list of all current files in the repo with ```git list-files -z``` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247387/3156906) and then do a case-insensitive search to find a match and get the correct casing for the file as it appears in the repo, but you *might* find multiple matches if ```a_TEST_file.txt``` and ```a_test_file.txt``` *both* exist in the repo…

Comment: @mclayton, I have rewritten the example script. It shows that `git log` requires correct letter case. The actual "not found" message came from `Get-GitHubContent` in the `PowerShellForGitHub` module.