# List all changed files with change status between Git commits (added, modified, deleted)

Tags: git, git-diff

I regularly use the following command to list files changed between two commits:

```
git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2
```

It gives a list of files somewhat like this:

```
/src/example/file1
/src/example/file2
/src/example/file3
```

There is almost no end to how useful this is.

**I'd really like to be able also to show alongside each file a brief reference to the change status, indicating whether a file was added, modified or deleted.**

Here's an example to demonstrate the concept:

```
git diff --name-only --and-how-me-the-change-status SHA1 SHA2
```

```
A /src/example/file1
M /src/example/file2
D /src/example/file3
```

The change status (A, M, D) is shown as an example only, I don't mind what this is so long as it is unambiguous.

I'm aware that I can use the `--diff-filter` option to list only added files, or only modified files or only deleted files. Using this option means I have to run three commands to get three lists of filenames. This is nice but could be nicer.

**Is there a single command I can run to give me the above example output?**

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340. It is very specific about asking for how to show the file status, not just a list of files.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `--name-status`, it's the same as `--name-only` plus the status of changed files:

```
git diff --name-status SHA1 SHA2
```

Comment: Brilliant, works a charm!

Comment: Also, make sure not to misplace SHA1 and SHA2. It will write `A` (added) instead of `D` (deleted) and vice-versa.

Comment: To sort by the change status, on Windows or Linux:

```git diff --name-status SHA1 SHA2 | sort```

Comment: Nice!
do you have a way to add a bit of colours ? :)