# Git command to show what came with the last git pull Modified, Deleted and Added files

Tags: git

I am currently using this Git command to show all modified files

```
git log --name-status -1 --oneline
```

What can I add to this command to show added and deleted files?

Comment: maybe duplicate? of this link:[StackOverflowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271435/list-all-changed-files-with-change-status-between-git-commits-added-modified)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I love this code because I do not have to go looking for the sha hash `git log --name-status -1 --oneline`   
Is there any way I can run this command without the sha hash?   
`git diff --name-status SHA1 SHA2`

Comment: Maybe you can look into the --diff-filter command I'm not entirely sure to be honest with you? I usually use the SHA command or something like it. Maybe you can try a command like this??                                                            git diff --name-only HEAD~20 HEAD~10 (you can use this command to see the difference between the 20th commit and 10th commit). Sorry, I'm not of more help.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I add to this command to show added and deleted files?

I'm not sure I understand the gap here.  I ran your command as-is on a test repo.

```
$ git log --name-status -1 --oneline
7517b16 3
M       file2
D       file3
A       file4
```

`file2` was modified (so line starts with `M`).  The line starting with `D` shows that `file3` was deleted.  The line starting with `A` shows that `file4` was added.