# Find deleted file in Git

Tags: git

I'm trying to recover a file that is no longer in a Git repository.

I can see that the file was created for sure when I run this:

```
git log --all --full-history --diff-filter=A --summary | grep filename
```

But I can't find when the file was deleted with this:

```
git log --all --full-history --diff-filter=D --summary | grep filename
```

The file for sure isn't there anymore, so why wouldn't it show up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all the deleted files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017987/how-can-i-list-all-the-deleted-files-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED** based on comments.

So the first thing was making sure that the `diff-filter` wasn't deceiving you, because if git sees the file as "moved" or "renamed" then `diff-filter` of `D` won't capture that.  But even taking the `diff-filter` out of the equation doesn't show the file being moved or removed.

That means it has never been moved or removed.  If you don't see it in the work tree, then either

(1) Removal of the file is staged but not committed
(2) Removal of the file is untracked
(3) The file was never on the current branch

I'm betting on (3).  The command you used to find the "create" record searches the history of all refs.  Take out the `--all` argument and ask for the history of your current commit

```
git log --full-history --diff-filter=A --summary | grep filename
```

Do you still see the file being created?  If not, then it was committed only on a different branch.  For example, if you have

```
x --- x --- H <--(master)
       \                ^HEAD
        A --- x <--(develop)
```

perhaps the file was added in commit `A`, which you would see in the history of `develop` (or when using `--all`).  But of course the file would not be in `H` (which is what you'd have checked out in this scenario) or its history.  So it wasn't deleted.

If the file *is* created in the current commit's history, but is never removed, then it's in the current commit.  The only reason left why you'd not see it is if it's been removed from the work tree, but the delete would be not yet committed and *maybe* not yet added.

Comment: If I run with the 'm' flag, it shows when the file was modified, but doesn't show it being re-named or anything.

Comment: If it showed when the file was modified, then you must've used `M`.  What you want is `m`

Comment: That shows it being created: `create mode 100644 filename.js`, but not anything else.

Comment: In that case, removal of the file from that path has not been committed in a way that's reachable from any ref.

Comment: Do you know what would cause that?

Comment: It's not exactly the right question.  If it hasn't been deleted in the commits, then the question is, why are you thinking it has?  New version of the answer might shed some light on it.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. `git log --full-history --diff-filter=A --summary | grep filename` doesn't return anything, but `git log --all --full-history --diff-filter=A --summary | grep filename` does show it being created. So I guess I need to figure out what branch it's hiding on.