# git list all files deleted in a project

Tags: git, github

Im beginner user to git
and I need to list all files has been deleted in a project.I want either there names or the total number of each one(ex. total number of files have been deleted) in a period of time.
another example ( I want to see all files deleted in the past two years in a project )
Im using Mac iOS and git on my terminal.
I tried this "git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete" but how can I add timestamp
I tried ls files command but I do not know how I can used it correctly.
Thank you

Comment: You're asking a few questions here.   I think `git ls-files` is the answer to one of them, I think `git log --diff-filter=... --format=...` probably answers your other one.  Try to limit to one question per question :)

Comment: thanks, I changed it to one question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git log` to see all your commits.

And if you do a `git show comit` it will show u the changes that happened for that commit.  That might be what you're looking for.

Try this `git log --diff-filter=D --since="2018-02-01"`

Comment: I don't want my commits, I want to see all files deleted in the past two years in a project for example.

Comment: check this out.. this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017987/how-can-i-list-all-the-deleted-files-in-a-git-repository

Comment: thanks I checked that but how do I specify a timestamp ? I want all files that have been deleted in the last two years?

Comment: add --since="2018-02-01" after that

Answer (score 1):

Try git status in terminal for a list of files to be committed. Also try git commit -a for a list of files that have been modified if you haven't committed them yet.

Comment: thanks for answering but I doing this to see all files in project not the files that I did add or delete