# Is it possible to know if a file existed in a folder of a repository in git?

Tags: git, github

I'd like to know if it's possible to know if a file existed inside a folder using git commands or using the github tools.

I checked using the git log, It shows the commits log, but it doesn't have information about which files were affected.

Comment: `git log filename.txt` will show you the history for `filename.txt`, regardless of whether it currently exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all the deleted files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017987/how-can-i-list-all-the-deleted-files-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to see the directories in given branch.

```
git ls-tree -d origin/master:<remote_dir><remote_subdir>
```