# How to list every file for every revision in Git (like Mercurial's hg manifest --all)?

Tags: git, mercurial

Mercurial has a command to list every file that the repository has for every revision:

```
hg manifest --all
```

Is there an equivalent command in Git? I know about `git ls-files`, but it only list files from the index (the current revision).

Comment: Related question (I think): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/git-list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give all the files ever existed:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq
```

Comment: I guess that the OP will also want to add `--all` to `git log`'s parameters, although even then it will miss dangling commits.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the following pipeline:

```
git rev-list HEAD | xargs -L 1 git ls-tree -r | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq
```

This does the following:

- use `git rev-list` to get a list of revisions backward from HEAD
- for each revision, use `git ls-tree -r` to show the list of files
- extract just the filenames from the list using awk
- using `sort` and `uniq`, filter out names that are listed more than once

This will give the name of every file that has ever been part of the history of the current HEAD.