# Git: List all files in a directory across all branches?

Tags: git

I've got some files I'm looking for but I'm not sure which branch they got put into. I'd like to list all the files for a given directory across all branches.

My question is, **in git, is there a way to list all files in a directory across all branches?**

Comment: Do you know the file names?

Comment: Judging from `git-ls-files` doc, one still has to check out the folder's contents from all the branches. So the direct approach is 1) get the branches list; 2) for each branch, checkout the folder and do git-ls-files on it.

Comment: we know the file pattern but not the exact file names

Comment: Did you try `git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -u`? These might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/543426/1076075 and http://superuser.com/a/429694

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the files in a directory using **git ls-tree**.

Here I'm writing the output of `git ls-tree` to a file.

```
$ for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/); do 
     git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch <directory> >> file-list ; 
  done
```

You can get the unique files by:

```
sort -u file-list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git ls-tree -r` to recursively list all files for a particular treeish. Combine with `git for-each-ref` to enumerate branches and some shell filtering.

```
for i in $(git for-each-ref '--format=%(refname)' 'refs/heads/*') ; do
  echo $i
  git ls-tree -r $i | awk '$4 ~ /filename-pattern/ {print $4}'
  echo
done
```

Replace `filename-pattern` with, well, a regular expression that matches the files that you're interested in. Remember to escape any slashes in the path.

Comment: To focus on a particular directory use `$i:path/to/it`, and I'm not sure but I think OP just wants the one dir, i.e. not `-r`.

Comment: Thanks @jthill. How would I do this? (Just one dir)

Comment: exactly as I put it there: replace your `$1` with `$1:path/to/it`, and if you don't want the recursive take out the `ls-tree`'s `-r`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587370/pratz

occasionally i found it useful to have also the branch name in the report

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/); do 
     git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch . |xargs -L 1 echo \#$branch: 
done
```