# GIT - Find all the files committed in a local branch

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project and I need to identify all the files changed/committed in a local branch in GIT.
Looking for an easy way which can go through all the commit and extract the files committed to the branch.

Comment: Unclear. Every commit consists of all the files, changed or not. If that’s what you want to know it’s easy. Is it? Also what does extract mean?

Comment: Okay to make it more specific, let's assume after creating a development branch from master, I committed and pushed some of my code files like:

```1st commit -> xyz.c, demo.sh -> and pushed to development branch```
```2nd commit -> run_schedule.perl, helloworld.c -> and pushed to development branch``` and so on.
I want to now find the files committed in both the commit, a GIT command which can read all the commits and give me : ```xyz.c, demo.sh, run_schedule.perl, helloworld.c```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all the files that ever existed in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari The command listed here is giving a lot of files which I don't think exists in my branch.

Comment: Files don't exist in *branches*. Files exist in *commits*. You need to pick some set of commits to query. Usually, you would pick exactly *two* commits—an old one, and a new one—and compare them to see what *changed* between those two.

Comment: If you want to have Git walk, one commit at a time, backwards through commits *reachable from* a branch name, use `git log <branch-name>`. To have Git *compare* each parent with each child (except for merge commits), add `-p` to this `git log` command. To see only the *names* of files changed, along with what the change was, use `--name-status`. To ignore what the change itself was and get only the *name*, use `--name-only`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `git diff --name-only`.

It takes two parameters. The first would be the name of your branch. The second would be the SHA at the point where the branch branched off from the parent branch. If you don't know what that is, `git merge-base` will tell you.

Example (here, `develop` is the common working branch, `mybranch` is my own):

```
$ git merge-base mybranch develop
4e5e735e9656dcf34a99827af6c2660a6c796d6f
$ git diff --name-only mybranch 4e5e73
```

You will see the list of names you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement, you need the diff between the local repo and the remote repo.

Let's take a look at what is different from our last commit to local repo from the remote repo by using the git diff command (diff of the local repo with the remote repo).

```
$ git diff HEAD origin/HEAD
```

Edit 1: As per your comment to this answer, try this if you are only interested in the list of names.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD origin/master
```

Comment: This shows the file level changes(changed content) in all commits, I only need list of files not the content of those

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana this should do it: git diff --name-only HEAD origin/master

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following comand

```
git log
```

This will show you the history of commits of the branch you are in, like this

```
commit a1b2c3d4e5 (feature/example-branch)
Author: exampleauthor <example@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 26 10:23:31 2020 -0300

    [REPO-3333] Example pull request (#333)
```

After that, you can use [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) (commit code) to extract the commits you want into a new branch. I use this when I have broken something and i don't know where.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it may not help, I want to use a single command which can list me all the files committed. ```git log``` will show me the individual commit info.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it? Just wanted to look for all options of doing this.

Comment: This is the way i know, i'd rather see the files and its changes in vscode. But if you come up with some other solution, would be grat too :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Please try this:

```
git log| grep commit | tr 'commit' ' ' | while read -r line ; do  echo "Processing $line"; git show --pretty="" --name-only $line; done
```

PS: Ignore the fatal lines, that comes from git log having response like 'Initial commit' rather than commit IDs which is not relevant here I guess.

Comment: `Please recheck this is what you want` @Biswajit Maharana

Comment: There is some error in the command it seems, it's showing a huge commit logs